# Is it possible to modify Django Q() objects after construction?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-q

Is it possible to modify Django Q() objects after construction?  I create a Q() object like so:

```
q = Q(foo=1)
```

is it possible to later change `q` to be the same as if I had constructed:

```
q2 = Q(foo=1, bar=2)
```

?  There's no mention of such an interface in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) that I could find.

I was looking for something like:

```
Q.append_clause(bar=2)
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "same as constructed"? do you mean modify the q object on the fly ?

Comment: @karthikr: Updated question to better describe what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok. the PerrinHarkins' answer is what you are looking for then.

Answer (score 6):

You can just make another Q() object and AND them together:
`q2 = q & Q(bar=2)`

Comment: Are you sure that's semantically identical?  It may well be, but I know there can be gotchas.  For instance, calling `.filter(Q(parent__foo=1)).filter(Q(parent__bar=1))` is different than `.filter(Q(parent__foo=1, parent__bar=1))` and I didn't want to fall afoul of anything like that.

Comment: Yes, they are identical. What matters is if there are two .filter calls or just one.

Answer (score 5):

You can add Q objects together, using their `add` method. For example:

```
>>> q = Q(sender=x)
>>> q.add(Q(receiver=y), Q.AND)
```

The second argument to `add` is the connector, which can also be `Q.OR`

**EDIT:** My answer is merely a different way of doing what Perrin Harkins suggested, but regarding your other concern, about different behavior of `filter` depending on the way you construct the query, you don't have to worry about that if you join Q objects. My example is equivalent to `filter(sender=x, receiver=y)`, and not `filter(sender=x).filter(receiver=y)`, because Q objects, as far as I could see in a quick test, do an immediate AND on the clauses and don't have the special behavior of `filter` for multi-valued relations.

In any case, nothing like looking at the SQL and making sure it really is doing the same in your specific queries.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are a little old and unsatisfactory imo. So here is my answer

This is how you deep copy:

```py
def deep_copy(q: Q) -> Q:
    new_q = Q()
    # Go through the children of a query: if it's another
    # query it will run this function recursively
    for sub_q in q.children:
        # Make sure you copy the connector in 
        # case of complicated queries
        new_q.connector = q.connector
        if isinstance(sub_q, Q):
            # This will run recursively on sub queries
            sub_q = get_employee_q(sub_q)
        else:
            pass # Do your modification here
        new_q.children.append(sub_q)
    return new_q
```

In the else condition is where your stuff (`name='nathan'` for example) is defined. You can change or delete that if you'd like and the Query should work fine.